# Python C API from C++ app - know when to lock

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, python-2.4

I am trying to write a C++ class that calls Python methods of a class that does some I/O operations (file, stdout) at once. The problem I have ran into is that my class is called from different threads: sometimes main thread, sometimes different others. Obviously I tried to apply the approach for Python calls in multi-threaded native applications. Basically everything starts from PyEval_AcquireLock and PyEval_ReleaseLock or just global locks. According to the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2/api/threads.html) when a thread is already locked a deadlock ensues. When my class is called from the main thread or other one that blocks Python execution I have a deadlock.

Python> Cfunc1() - C++ func that creates threads internally which lead to calls in "my class",
It stuck on PyEval_AcquireLock, obviously the Python is already locked, i.e. waiting for C++ Cfunc1 call to complete...  It completes fine if I omit those locks. Also it completes fine when Python interpreter is ready for the next user command, i.e. when thread is calling funcs in the background - not inside of a native call

I am looking for a workaround. I need to distinguish whether or not the global lock is allowed, i.e. Python is not locked and ready to receive the next command...  I tried PyGIL_Ensure, unfortunately I see hang.

Any known API or solution for this ?

(Python 2.4)

Comment: Have you got some sort of message pump, where you send messages which are handled on the main thread?

Comment: Can you clarify how the threads are spawned?  Are they spawned via the Python API?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have wrapped your C++ code quite peculiarly, when *any* Python thread calls into your C++ code, the GIL is **held**.  You may **release** it in your C++ code (if you want to do some consuming task that doesn't require any Python interaction), and then will have to acquire it again when you want to do any Python interaction -- see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock): if you're just using the good old C API, there are macros for that, and the recommended idiom is

```
Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
...Do some blocking I/O operation...
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
```

the docs explain:

> The Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS macro opens
>   a new block and declares a hidden
>   local variable; the
>   Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS macro closes the
>   block. Another advantage of using
>   these two macros is that when Python
>   is compiled without thread support,
>   they are defined empty, thus saving
>   the thread state and GIL
>   manipulations.

So you just don't have to acquire the GIL (and shouldn't) until after you've explicitly released it (ideally with that macro) *and* need to interact with Python in any way again. (Where the docs say "some blocking I/O operation", it could actually be any long-running operation with no Python interaction whatsoever).

Comment: I have finally found the workaround I was looking for..

if (_PyThreadState_Current == NULL)
{
     state = PyGILState_Ensure()
}

... 
PyGILState_Release(state)

I needed to register the thread in Python, it seem to work fine.
Currently testing the fix...